# How to test the presence of a node (string) in an xml file to use in a loop to extract data from multiple files?

Tags: r, xml, if-statement, xml-parsing

As a new R user I've been struggling with this problem for a while and could not figure it out on my own. Perhaps the answer is simple, and someone can help me. My challenge is that I have thousands of xm files in a folder and I want to extract the content of a specific node from each of them and save in a dataframe. The files, however, have repetition of the names for my node of interest. So I used numbers instead of names to extract the data I want.

```
for (i in (1 : length(file_list))) {
  
test.file<- file_list[i]
datax<-xmlParse(test.file)  #enter the xml file name you want to analyze
data<-xmlToList(datax) #convert xml as a list
serial<-as.vector(unlist(data$.attrs[2]))
print(serial)

# Check if the xml file contains the node AuditRules

n <- ifelse(xml_find_all(test.file, "//AuditRules") == TRUE, 6, 5)

#Extract waveform values for the Current ECG srip

waveform <- as.vector(data[[n]][[3]][[1]][[1]][[2]])
waveform <- as.character(waveform)
waveform<-strsplit(waveform, split = " ")
waveform<-as.numeric(unlist(waveform))
waveform<-as.data.frame(waveform)

#Extract the serial number to be used as ID for the animal and create a column on the dataframe

serial<-as.vector(unlist(data$.attrs[2]))
serial<-as.factor(serial)
waveform$serial<-serial

#Extract date and time of Current ECG and save it as a column date

date<-as.vector(unlist(data$.attrs[n]))
date <- gsub("T", " ", date)
waveform$date <- as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'Etc/GMT+5')

#Extract time offset [the first R-R interval from the Current ECG ]

offset <-as.vector(unlist(data[[n]][[3]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]))
offset <- gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", offset)
waveform$offset <- offset

#Crate a column for voltage in mv using the  amplitudeScaleFactor="0.000815" 
#waveform$mv <- waveform$waveform*0.000815

#Create a column for time (sec) using the sampleInterval="PT0.0078125S"

#waveform$time <- as.numeric(waveform$offset)
# add a new column to old data.frame. Set value "offset"  as the starting value for row 1.

# populate newcol with values starting from row 2.

#for (i in 4:nrow(waveform)){
#  waveform[i,6] <- waveform[i-1,6] +0.0078125

# Write data to CSV  
 
 write.csv(waveform, paste0(data_export_dir,"/Savannah_", file_names[i],"_ECG.csv"))
}
```

My Problem: Some files have one extra node before the node of interest [5]. For those I would need to change the node of interest to [6] instead.
My question: How could I change the above code to include a condition (presence or absence of the extra node) and alternate the use of [5] or [6] accordingly.
I tried to add something like this to my loop, but it did not work:

```
for (i in (1 : length(file_list))) {
  
test.file<- file_list[i]
datax<-xmlParse(test.file)  
data<-xmlToList(datax) #convert xml as a list
serial<-as.vector(unlist(data$.attrs[2]))
print(serial)

# Check if the xml file contains the node AuditRules

n <- ifelse(xml_find_all(test.file, "//AuditRules") == TRUE, 6, 5)

#Extract waveform values for the Current ECG srip

waveform <- as.vector(data[[n]][[3]][[1]][[1]][[2]])
waveform <- as.character(waveform)
waveform<-strsplit(waveform, split = " ")
waveform<-as.numeric(unlist(waveform))
waveform<-as.data.frame(waveform)
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Example of the structure of the xml file I want to extract data from:

```
xml.file.a <- c(<SessionInfo><BatteryData><AuditRules><Counters><Trend><CardiacOccurrenceRecord><OccurrenceDateTime><DateTime>2019-07-02T06:05:00</DateTime></OccurrenceDateTime><OccurrenceType><Discrete>CurrentECG</Discrete></OccurrenceType><EpisodeRecord episodeRecordLength="PT10.842S"><Strip><WaveformChannel amplitudeResolution="0.000815" amplitudeScaleFactor="0.000815" amplitudeUnit="mV" sampleInterval="PT0.0078125S"><WaveformSegment length="PT0.607S" offset="PT0S" state="EgmNotStored"/><WaveformSegment length="PT10.235S" offset="PT0.607S" samples="-456 -454 -454 -458 -457 -457 -459 -457 -459 -460 -459 -458 -460 -463  " state="Stored"/><WaveformSegment length="PT0S" offset="PT10.842S" state="EndRecording"/></CardiacOccurrenceRecord><CardiacOccurrenceRecord><CardiacOccurrenceRecord>

xml.file.b <- c(<SessionInfo><BatteryData><Counters><Trend><CardiacOccurrenceRecord><OccurrenceDateTime><DateTime>2019-07-02T06:05:00</DateTime></OccurrenceDateTime><OccurrenceType><Discrete>CurrentECG</Discrete></OccurrenceType><EpisodeRecord episodeRecordLength="PT10.842S"><Strip><WaveformChannel amplitudeResolution="0.000815" amplitudeScaleFactor="0.000815" amplitudeUnit="mV" sampleInterval="PT0.0078125S"><WaveformSegment length="PT0.607S" offset="PT0S" state="EgmNotStored"/><WaveformSegment length="PT10.235S" offset="PT0.607S" samples="-456 -454 -454 -458 -457 -457 -459 -457 -459 -460 -459 -458 -460 -463  " state="Stored"/><WaveformSegment length="PT0S" offset="PT10.842S" state="EndRecording"/></CardiacOccurrenceRecord><CardiacOccurrenceRecord><CardiacOccurrenceRecord>
```

I need to extract the following data segment from the first  node:

```
<WaveformSegment length="PT10.235S" offset="PT0.607S"samples="-456 -454 -454 -458 -457 -457 -459 -457 -459 -460 -459 -458 -460 -463  "state="Stored"/><WaveformSegment length="PT0S" offset="PT10.842S"
```

When I tried to use the following code, I extracted the all the segments for all nodes named **CardiacOcurrenceRecord** and could not figure out how to only get the first one.

```
xml_1 <- xmlParse("20200116_020831_RLA496828S.xml")
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xml_1) 
xpathSApply(xmltop, '//WaveformSegment[2]')
```

Comment: Hi moraisrn can you provide a sample json file to demonstrate what you want.

Comment: There are easier ways to select the node of choice but without seeing an example it is difficult to provide a meaningful advice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added some more info that might be useful. Please, let me know if uploading a file would be even better. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xpathSApply()` function is returning a list of all WaveformSegments.  Once you have that list, it is just a matter of using `[[ ]]` to access the individual list elements.

Also note in my example below I used a "." in the XPath, this is to indicate to search only below this node as opposed to the entire document.  In this case it doesn't matter since the variable "xmltop" is the entire document, but with we started with just the "EpisodeRecord" then we may only want the "Waveform Segment" for just that one node.

```
library(XML)
#find top root
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xml_1) 
#Find the Second WaveformSegment in all nodes - returns a list
CardiacOccurrence<-xpathSApply(xmltop, './/WaveformSegment[2]')
#access the first element in the list
CardiacOccurrence[[1]]

#obtain vector of attributes
attrs<-xmlAttrs(CardiacOccurrence[[1]])

attrs[["samples"]]
#[1] "-456 -454 -454 -458 -457 -457 -459 -457 -459 -460 -459 -458 -460 -463  "
```

Hope this answers or question.

Comment: Thank you so much! With this hint, my code now is much simpler and I can extract exactly what I want from all files at once even when the root structure is different.

Comment: @moraism, Awesome, glad to hear it.  XPath can be tricky but with practice it becomes a very powerful tool.  Glad to have helped,